# Access parent properties

Tags: swift

I want to access a property of a parent Annotation Class I wrote to check for it's value.

**Annotation.swift**

```
enum AnnotationType: Int {
    case AnnotationDefault = 0
    case AnnotationAED
    case AnnotationResponder
    case AnnotationIncident
}

class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subTitle: String
    var type: AnnotationType

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subTitle: String, type: AnnotationType) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subTitle = subTitle
        self.type = type
    }

    func getType() -> AnnotationType {
        return self.type
    }
}
```

**AEDAnnotation.swift**

```
class AEDAnnotation : Annotation {
    let aed: AED

    init(aed: AED) {
        self.aed = aed
        super.init(coordinate: aed.coordinate, title: aed.street, subTitle: aed.owner, type: aed.annotationType)
    }

    func getAnnotationType() -> AnnotationType {
        return super.getType()
    }
}
```

I create an annotation like this:

```
let annotation = AEDAnnotation.init(aed: aed)
self.annotationArray.append(annotation)
```

if I loop through the array, I see that there are valid AEDAnnotations in there. But why can't I access the underlying property of `Annotation.swift` which I am asking for.

```
for item in self.annotationArray {
    print(item.getType)
}
```

This does not work. But how can I get access to the property `type` of `Annotation.swift`

The Error message I get is:
`Value of type 'MKAnnotation' has no member 'getType'`

Comment: You should be able to access the type property of the parent class, based on your code.  You say it doesn't work, but do not provide the error, how does it not work?

Comment: I added the error to the question. I am confused why this is an item of type `MKAnnotation` where I expect it to be of type AEDAnnotation. When I print the description of `item` it show `AEDAnnotation` correctly as array item.

Comment: Yeah, that's a little strange.  Is your array getting populated anywhere aside from the two lines of code you included in your question?

Comment: Nope. Only in this part. The ouput of printing the array shows <AEDAnnotation>,<AEDAnnotation> like expected.

Comment: Actually, I don't see where you declare annotationArray.  Is it declared as an array of type MKAnnotation?

Comment: erm.. yeah.. it is... it should be of type Annotation ,right?

Comment: Ha.. now it works!!!! Can you answer the question please? then I can mark your answer is awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that `item` is of type `MKAnnnotation`.  If you want to treat it as a different type you will need to cast it.  Try the following:

```
for item in self.annotationArray {
    if let myAnnotation = item as Annotation {
        print("\(myAnnotation.getType().rawValue)")
    }
    else {
        print("Annotation was not an Annotation type")
    }
}
```